# Textbox Twoway Multibinding requires Path or XPath

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, multibinding

I have an ItemsControl with several cells/views that display data from 2 different lists.

The first list contains all possible cards in a specific card set.

The second list contains only the card number and the amount per rarity of cards that were collected.

To display the amount and to increase/decrease the amount of cards in the second list with collected cards is already working with a converter.

**Problem**

The problem is now that I want to be able to also type in the exact amount of cards collected.
But when I use TwoWay instead of OneWay Binding it throws an error with 'TwoWay Binding requires Path or XPath'.

I already checked other posts but they are mainly about DataGrid or just about single bindings instead of MultiBinding.

Picture of view at runtime:

[image]

**The View containing the cell information:**

```
<TextBox>
                    <TextBox.Text>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource CollectedMagicCardAmountCollectedConverter}" Mode="OneWay">
                            <!-- Pass the datacontext as the first parameter -->
                            <Binding/>
                            <Binding Path="DataContext.ActiveCollectedMagicCardSet" 
                                     RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}"/>
                            <Binding Source="EN"/>
                            <Binding Source="Normal"/>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </TextBox.Text>
                </TextBox>
```

**Converter**

```
public class CollectedMagicCardAmountCollectedConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            int amount = 0;
            if(values != null && values.Length == 4)
            {
                var magicCard = values[0] as MagicCard;
                var collectedMagicCardSet = values[1] as CollectedMagicCardSet;
                var languageKeyString = values[2] as string;
                var rarityKeyString = values[3] as string;
                


                if (magicCard != null 
                    && collectedMagicCardSet != null 
                    && collectedMagicCardSet.CollectedCards != null 
                    && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(languageKeyString) 
                    && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(rarityKeyString))
                {
                    LanguageKey languageKey = (LanguageKey)Enum.Parse(typeof(LanguageKey), languageKeyString);
                    if (collectedMagicCardSet.CollectedCards.ContainsKey(languageKey))
                    {
                        List<CollectedMagicCard> currentCollectedMagicSet = collectedMagicCardSet.CollectedCards[languageKey];
                        if(currentCollectedMagicSet != null && currentCollectedMagicSet.Count > 0)
                        {
                            var collectedMagicCard = currentCollectedMagicSet.Find(m => m.CollectorNumber == magicCard.CollectorNumber);
                            if(collectedMagicCard != null)
                            {
                                RarityKey rarityKey = (RarityKey)Enum.Parse(typeof(RarityKey), rarityKeyString);

                                if (collectedMagicCard.AmountPerRarity != null && collectedMagicCard.AmountPerRarity.ContainsKey(rarityKey))
                                {
                                    amount = collectedMagicCard.AmountPerRarity[rarityKey];
                                }
                            }
                            

                        }

                    }
                }
            }
            


            return amount.ToString();
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Comment: `<Binding Path="." />` afaik, this would work.

Comment: When I change the first of the four bindings to `<Binding Path="."/>` I still get the same error.
I already tried this after googling the error.

Comment: `<Binding Path="DataContext" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}"/>` then, also change `Window` to proper control type which has explicitly `DataContext` assigned.

Comment: When I change the first of the four Bindings to `<Binding Path="DataContext" 
                                     RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}"/>` I still get the same error.
The commands on my buttons next to the Textbox which have the same Bindings just work fine. They can call the commands on my Viewmodel with the correct parameters. I just can't use the TextBox to write the values. It is not a problem to get the Binding to the ViewModel but that TwoWay Binding seems not to work with MultiBinding.